# form action doesn't use php and instead appends php filename to url

Tags: php, forms, action

I'm stumped. I use this code pattern elsewhere and it works fine, but I'm getting an undesired behavior in this instance. I've searched and found no other reference to this issue.

My form code:

```
<form method="post" id="quoteForm" action="process_acceptance.php">
   <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr><h1>Contract Confirmation</h1></tr>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="record_number"></td>
            <td><center><b><input type="submit" value="Approve" /></b></center></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The php redirects the user to a thank you page and does some processing (as noted earlier, this code functions perfectly elsewhere, but I'm including it so you can see the ACTION isn't going into a black hole of some sort):

```
<?php

// Release user
ignore_user_abort(true);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: 0');
header('Location: confirm_acceptance.php');
flush();
...
?>
```

Instead of executing the php code in the ACTION= value, it reloads the page and appends the name of the php file to the URL.

Any ideas on where to look to find out what's going wrong?

Comment: From what url are you accessing the form initially?  You have a relative URL in the action, so if you're using seo-friendly urls or starting at a directory root, you may have issues with the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a value to your hidden input..

```
<input type="hidden" value="myrecordnumber" name="record_number">
```

you're not sending PHP any data to work with..

Comment: @user2033578 Sorry, i fixed my answer. if this helped please check the checkbox to the left to accept this answer.